# Pad HTML Table Columns, Two Borders?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to add space between columns, but maintain a border on both sides?  See the following image:

[image]

Comment: That's possible, you should really post some CSS/HTML though in order to get a solution that fits your implementation. Maybe set up a JSFiddle too.

Answer (score 4):

One option is using the `border-spacing` CSS rule. Something like this:

```
table {
  border-spacing: 10px 0;
}
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/ABAQiBI/1/edit) is a quick example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `border-spacing`.

```
table { 
      border-spacing: 10px 0;
}
```

For more table related styles you can check this http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html

Comment: I was under the impression border collapse only supported the values 'separate' and 'collapse'. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @mookamafoob Sorry, disabled not there for border-collapse. Im editing my answer

Answer (score 2):

Border spacing css attribute will fix your problem.

```
table {
border-spacing: 10px 0;
}
```